# How do i use an 'if' on a checkbutton in tkinter. (python 3.8)

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a new button called `btn3` which is meant to do the command `checkbox1`.But the 'if' command needs to know the state of the checkbutton. How do you do that. It says no attribute called onvalue. I've checked other stackoverflow questions similar to this but they don't answer my question or doesn't work.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title("Anti Bullying App")
window.geometry("555x100")

def checkbox1():
    if c1.onvalue == 1:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Report It!", icon = "warning")

ayb = Label(window, text = "                 Are you being bullied?         ", font = "Ariel 20   bold")
ayb.grid()

var1 = IntVar()
var2 = IntVar()

c1 = Checkbutton(window, text='Yes', font = "10",variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
c1.grid()
c2 = Checkbutton(window, text='No', font = "10",variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
c2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
btn3 = Button(window, text = "submit", command = checkbox1)
```

Comment: You have an `IntVar()` so why not use that in your function?

Comment: How do you do that and what do you mean

Comment: `if var1.get() == 1:`

Comment: Also you never assigned a command to your Checkbutton's. How do you expect it to know what function it is using?

Comment: sorry about that forget the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do here however the most likely option is to use `get()` on your `IntVar()`.

You will need to do a bit of clean up though.

Take a look at the below and let me know if you have any questions. I have cleaned up you code to follow PEP8 more closely and added some geometry configs to even things out so you do not need to add a bunch of spaces to your label.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.title('Anti Bullying App')
root.geometry('555x100')


def checkbox1():
    if var1.get() == 1:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'Report It!', icon='warning')


tk.Label(root, text='Are you being bullied?', font='Ariel 20 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')

var1 = tk.IntVar(root, value=0)
var2 = tk.IntVar(root, value=0)

tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Yes', font='10', variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ew')
tk.Checkbutton(root, text='No', font='10', variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ew')
tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=checkbox1).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]